# about algorithm complexity measurement

Tags: logging, big-o, time-complexity

hey guys i'm new here so i'll try to keep it as clear as i can.

on my current exercise i'm to demonstrate the time differences between several sorting algorithms. for a more precise result i took a few different sizes of arrays (sorted,unsorted) and got my results. i understand the meaning of o, big O, and so on... so my question is about the meaning of theta in merge sort. to be more clear i know that the complexity of this specific algorithm is n*log(n), what i don't understand is what happens when i get a result for example 15000 ms in an array of size 2000 - if i place it in the function n*log(n) shouldn't i get the same number as provided by the system ? or am i whey off ?

i hope my question is understandable thanks .

Comment: You will probably receive a better answer at http://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Big O is meant to represent the trend of an algorithms performance as it approaches a limit, not to express the result for any specific value of N.  For example, if an algorithm's performance can be expressed by f(x) = 2x + x^2, then it has  Big O of x^2.

Also, Big O is hardware independent.

If you want to see the relationship between your times and Big O, run the algorithm lots of times with increasing values of n and chart the results.  You'll see the time follows a graph similar to the one described by the Big O.

Comment: i understand that the meaning is that it can only approach the limit and i did in fact chart the result but my question is about theta - if the limits are from top and bottom what does it mean when i place the n value in the function ? its a little difficult for me to understand it.